# The reason behind the Crestfallen Warrior?

Tags: dark-souls

As the player first comes across the [**Firelink Shrine**](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Firelink_Shrine), there is a knight named [**Crestfallen Warrior**](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Crestfallen_Warrior) sitting against a ledge of grass.

My question is, is he only a dialogue character?
Was there any *planned* reason for having him?
Is there some lore about him on how he got there?
I basically want to know what the point of including him is, other than the fact that he gives tips.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Typically with *Souls* games, there is very little in-depth lore (*Dark Souls*'s main quest is the one exception) and most of anything is really little more than educated guesses.

Comment: Why would they do that exactly? @Yukki

Comment: It lends the game a sense of mystery and encourages community building.

Comment: @Yukki Not trying to sound rude, but how would I be able to find an answer for this if one at all?

Comment: While there is no canon answer, you can look at various wikis and forums for other people's takes on it.

Comment: Hmmm... Alright then. Was actually looking for the "canon" answer though. So what should I do with this question then?

Comment: Up to you. You can delete it or leave it up. I can give a write up on the most popular theory if you want.

Comment: @Yukki *I can give a write up on the most popular theory if you want.* Sure! I would like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is widely believed that the Crestfallen Warrior is another Chosen Undead, one who fears losing his grasp on Humanity and becoming Hollow. Thus, he refuses to venture outside of Firelink Shrine. This is evidenced by his knowledge of the path up to the second Bell of Awakening. He has tried several times to ring the second Bell of Awakening and has also seen many other fail in the attempt. Thus, he claims that the path of Chosen Undead, the ringing of the second Bell of Awakening, is "impossible" or "suicide".

Then, when the player character rings the second Bell and awakens Kingseeker Frampt, the Crestfallen Warrior is struck with a sense of amazement. How could this person ring the "impossible" second Bell? Thus, he journeys to the New Londo Ruins and becomes Hollow. Here, his motivations are unclear. Was he simply twisted by jealousy and resentment and turned Hollow? Or was he inspired by your impossible achievement and made one last tragic attempt at completing his quest?

Comment: Mmm. Haven't gotten to the second one yet. xD Makes sense though. You got my approval.

Comment: Interesting theory. I was always under the impression that Frampt's snoring drove him mad and he went to The New Londo ruins seeking the assistance of Kaathe.

Comment: Well, just rang the second bell of awakening, saw Kingseeker and your post makes absolute sense. He even said something like: "I need to do something about this..." probably meaning "Lets go to the ruins!"